# Magento - Move Toolbar to Left block

Tags: php, magento-1.6

I am having problems moving Product List toolbar from content block to left block.

I would like to display only sort-by option, which is easily done by setting up a custom toolbar template file toolbar_custom.html. But I get an error by output.

So far I added this lines in `layout/catalog.xml`:

```xml
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_custom.phtml"/>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

---

and this in `navigation/left.phtml`:

```php
<?php $magento_block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout'); ?>
<?php $toolbarHtml = $magento_block->createBlock('catalog/product_list'); ?>
<?php $toolbarHtml->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar_custom.phtml'); ?>
<?php echo $toolbarHtml ->toHTML(); ?>
```

---

This is my custom toolbar template - `toolbar_custom.phtml`:

```php
<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="toolbar">
    <?php if( $this->isExpanded() ): ?>
        <div class="sort-by">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
                <?php var_dump($this->getName()); ?>
                <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
       </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

---

As I open the product listing page in browser I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in
>   magento/app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar_custom.phtml
>   on line 37

I am using Magento Community 1.6..

Answer (score 1):

Under the layout/catalog.xml file do the changes in the Default section..

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
 </block>
```

include the above code inside this reference part

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.categorymenu" before="cart_sidebar"  template="catalog/navigation/left_catalog.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

you can use your own toolbar.phtml file inside the block

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This worked for me:

In layout/catalog.xml in the `<reference name="left">` block, insert:

`<block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog_product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"></block>`

Then, in left.phtml where you want the toolbar:

```
<?php
  $toolbar = $this->getChild('catalog_product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
  $toolbar->setCollection($this->getChild('catalog_product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection());
  echo $toolbar->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: this solution displays the toolbar but does apply category restrictions to sort orders i.e

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your layout:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
  <reference name="left">       
        <!-- Adds the toolbar to the left column -->
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.page.toolbar" template="catalog/category/sidetoolbar.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml" />
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>

        <!-- We use the original toolbar - you could also write your own -->
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

And create a new template at catalog/category/sidetoolbar.phtml:

```
<?php 
// lets get the toolbar block
$toolbar = $this->getChild('product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
// add the product collection
$toolbar->setCollection($this->getChild('product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection());
?>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/viezel

Answer (score -1):

Just rename the blocks like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar_custom" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_custom.phtml"/>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar_custom</name></action>
```